# How to read and display the contents of a text file in nasm?

Tags: linux, nasm, system-calls, file-handling

I want to read and display the contents of a text file using nasm and Linux system calls. My text file is named "new.txt". I wrote the following code and am receiving no output on the terminal.

```
section .data
    line db "This is George,",
        db " and his first line.", 0xa, 0
    len equ $ - line
    line2 db "This is line number 2.", 0xa, 0
    len2 equ $ - line2
filename:   db 'ThisIsATestFile.txt', 0

section .bss
    bssbuf: resb len    ;any int will do here, even 0,
    file: resb 4        ;since pointer is allocated anyway

global _start
section .text
_start:
; open file in read-only mode

    mov eax, 5      ;sys_open file with fd in ebx
    mov ebx, filename       ;file to be opened
    mov ecx, 0      ;O_RDONLY
    int 80h

    cmp eax, 0      ;check if fd in eax > 0 (ok)
    jbe error       ;can not open file

    mov ebx, eax        ;store new (!) fd of the same file

; read from file into bss data buffer

    mov eax, 3      ;sys_read
    mov ecx, bssbuf     ;pointer to destination buffer
    mov edx, len        ;length of data to be read
    int 80h
    js error        ;file is open but cannot be read

    cmp eax, len        ;check number of bytes read
    jb close        ;must close file first

; write bss data buffer to stderr

    mov eax, 4      ;sys_write
    push ebx        ;save fd on stack for sys_close
    mov ebx, 2      ;fd of stderr which is unbuffered
    mov ecx, bssbuf     ;pointer to buffer with data
    mov edx, len        ;length of data to be written
    int 80h

    pop ebx         ;restore fd in ebx from stack

close:
    mov eax, 6  ;sys_close file
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1  ;sys_exit
    mov ebx, 0  ;ok
    int 80h

error:
    mov ebx, eax    ;exit code
    mov eax, 1  ;sys_exit
    int 80h
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
    jb close        ;must close file first
```

you, in fact, are *jumping* to close, not calling it.

Once you reach close, you just exit after you close the file:

```
close:
    mov eax, 6  ;sys_close file
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1  ;sys_exit
    mov ebx, 0  ;ok
    int 80h
```

Perhaps you want to either `call` close in some way (and then `ret` from close) or jump back to where you were to continue what you were doing?

Also, keep in mind that `jbe` is an *unsigned* comparison, so when you write:

```
cmp eax, 0      ;check if fd in eax > 0 (ok)
jbe error       ;can not open file
```

You in fact will not detect negative numbers. Consider `jle` instead. (You can consult [this handy resource](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) about jumps to use.)